# Is it okay to have a trailing semicolon in a Set-Cookie header?

Tags: cross-browser

An example from MDN for how to set cookies is the following `Set-Cookie` Header:

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>; Secure; HttpOnly
```

In most of the places I've seen, there's no semicolon at the end. I'm wondering, is it ok to have a trailing semicolon? Something like this:

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>; Secure; HttpOnly;
```

I'm just curious, what are the RFCs saying and how are the different browsers treating it, do they all accept it?